# API call in a custom hook useEffect is fired only once (even when hook is used coupld of times)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom hook called `useBooksData`. Inside I have lots of constants, functions and one API call in `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (books === null) {
      getBooks();
    }
  }, []);
```

Then I'm using the `useBooksData` hook in a couple of places, even on the same page, f.ex.:

```
const { data } = useBooksData();
```

or in another component (same page):

```
const { loading } = useBooksData();
```

and in yet another one:

```
const { numberOfBooks } = useBooksData();
```

Since I'm using (initializing) the `useBooksData` hook couple of times, when I think longer about that, my expectation would be the number of times it is used, the number of API calls (`getBooks`) will be fired... However when I look into the Network tab in my browser there is only one... Why?

Comment: Are your `books` var and `getBooks` function both global, or a state in another component? You would probably want a state either in the component, or inside your hook. If you save your books globally, they will only be set once, and any further checks will see it as filled

Comment: They are saved in a redux store and the `if books === null` handle the case when changing the pages that use `useBooksData`. However when I open one particular page the data is `null` and the `useBooksData` is used multiple times in multiple components on that page so my expectation would be that it will request the data multiple times

Comment: I think we will need to see more about where and how the store is written and the data is handled. My assumption is that since you are checking if they exist first, you will only hit the actual fetching once, otherwise the existing copy will be returned